# Spring Data not updating on latest data

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a field in my SQL table which needs to be updated by one and return a unique ID. But looks like it is not being updated on the latest data, especially when I give a lot of requests.

```
@Transactional
public interface CompanyRepository extends CrudRepository<Company, Integer> {    
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true, flushAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = "update Company c set c.accessId = :accessId WHERE c.id = :companyId AND c.accessId = :oldAccessId", nativeQuery = true)
    int updateAccessId(@Param("companyId") Integer companyId, @Param("accessId") Integer accessId, @Param("oldAccessId") Integer oldAccessId);
}
```

Even with both clearAutomatically and flushAutomatically set to true, it is not working on the latest data.

I could see two update query being successful both with oldAccessId as the same.

Should the table design be changed?

PS : I have tried without nativeQuery = true as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is a classical race condition.

Two threads read the same entity, with identical `accessId`, increment it by one and then writing the result using the method you show in your question. Resulting in effectively only one update.

There are various ways how to fix this.

1. Use JPA and optimistic locking.

   Assuming you have an attribute with `@Version` annotated you can do the 
   following in a single transactional method:

   1. Load the entity.
   2. increment the `accessId`.
   3. persist the entity.

   If another transaction tries to do the same on the same entity one of the two will get an exception. In that case retry until the update goes through.
2. Use the database.

   Make reading and updating atomic in the database. Instead of passing the new value as parameter use a query like this one:

   ```
   update Company c 
   set c.accessId = c.accessId + 1 
   WHERE c.id = :companyId
   ```
3. Make it a version attribute.

   As mentioned above JPA already has `@Version` attributes which get updated on every change. Depending on the exact requirements you might be able to make `accessId` simply that attribute and get it updated automatically.
4. Check if any rows got updated.

   Based on your comment your intention was to basically reimplement what JPA does with version attributes. If you do this you are missing a crucial part: checking that the update actually updated anything, by comparing the return value against 1.

Comment: I think I see where you are heading. I added option #4.

Comment: The reason why I have oldAccessId is to avoid race condition. Basically the row needs to be updated only if the accessId is still oldAccessId. Otherwise the update should fail.

Comment: Yes I am checking the result and retrying  as well. Just that I have not put the code.

Comment: My sincere apologies to you and everyone else who took their time to go through this. This question is invalid. There was some other thread reading the entity and doing a save, causing a race condition. I had not noticed that until now.

Comment: The code for updating the id is perfectly correct, just that in my application there was another thread doing a read and save. So that was what causing duplication in the accessId. Should I mark this question as invalid or answered?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's out of scope/can't be reproduced. But I think the combination of question is still valid so I'd leave it as it is.